# Office store app working with local url

Tags: visual-studio-2013, office365

I am developing an app for Office (task pane app). This app would be deployed on to public Office Store in order to be accessible by our customers. Once the app is added to the document, I would like the app to talk to the local (intranet) web server to retrieve data.

I have gone through some documentation on MSDN, but it is not very clear if this can be implemented.

Basically, can the SourceLocation url in office manifest xml file be determined at the runtime instead of configuring a static one? I see this value has ~remoteUrl when developing app using VS 2013. Can I store the intranet web server url in the document and use the value to overwrite the "~remoteUrl" at runtime? Or please let me know if there is any other way to resolve this issue.

```
<DefaultSettings>
  <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteUrl/abc/index.html" />
</DefaultSettings>
```

Comment: I know this is resurfacing quite an old post, but Microsoft still doesn't support wild cards or the like in the manifest file, and we have many customers with their own subdomains. I was curious if you were able to find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the intranet addresses in your manifest file under `AppDomains` tag?

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>http://intranet.yourcompany.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>http://192.168.0.1</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

Comment: I cannot add intranet address to the manifest file directly as the application is targeted for multiple customers and they all would have different intranet addresses.